How to use Jsonnet to create Docker Compose File with Alias
In am using jsonnet to create docker compose file.  I am at just initial stages, and I need an alias &image because I will reuse this in other section later.
function(spec, service) {
  version: spec.version.compose_version,
  services: {
    [service + '-primary']: {
      image: '&image ' + spec.registry + '/' + service  ':' + spec.version
    }
  }
}

But this will output
"services":
  "ourproduct-primary":
    "image": "&image mycompany.com/ourproduct:${VERSION:-master}"
"version": "3.9"

I think this is not valid as &image and the link are both enclosed in same double quotes, I don't know how to solve.
Also is there a way to remove the double quotes? So it would look like this?
version: '3.9'

services:
  ourproduct-primary:
    image: &image mycompany.com/ourproduct:${VERSION:-master}

I am using manifestYamlDoc
function(spec){
  ['compose.%s.yaml' % service]: std.manifestYamlDoc(services[service](spec, service))
  for service in spec.services
}


Can you write a function that produces the image name, and include it everywhere you need it?  The documentation for std.manifestYamlDoc doesn't obviously suggest any support for generating YAML anchors.

As surely already found, std.manifestYamlDoc() doesn't have a flag to unquote values (as it does have quote_keys=false), but even other ad-hoc tools like yq will find the &, take it verbatim, then quote it (see output#1 below).
I think the only solution is to post-replace some arbitrary string very late in the CLI invocation:
src: foo.libsonnet
// foo.libsonnet
function(spec, service) {
  services: {
    [service + '-primary']: {
      image: 'YAML_ALIASimage ' + spec.registry + '/' + service + ':' + spec.version,
    },
  },
}

src: foo.jsonnet
// foo.jsonnet
local libfoo = import 'foo.libsonnet';

std.manifestYamlDoc(
  { version: '3.9' }
  + libfoo({ registry: 'docker.io/bar', version: '${VERSION:-master}' }, 'baz')
)

output#1
Note that yq even quotes it:
$ jsonnet -S foo.jsonnet  | sed 's/YAML_ALIAS/\&/' | yq -y .
services:
  baz-primary:
    image: '&image docker.io/bar/baz:${VERSION:-master}'
version: '3.9'

output#2
Late post-processing ftw (same as output#1 but changed piping order):
jsonnet -S foo.jsonnet  | yq -y . | sed 's/YAML_ALIAS/\&/'
services:
  baz-primary:
    image: &image docker.io/bar/baz:${VERSION:-master}
version: '3.9'

